# Ansible - Role default values changed per grouping

Tags: ansible

I am still new to Ansible so everything has been a huge learning experience so far.. Please go easy!

I am looking to implement the following in a best practice approach but I can't quite seem to wrap my head around it, or rather, I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to accomplish the same goal..

Specifically, I am trying to apply a role that has a number of default parameters set.. Something specific for whether or not xinet is needed for example.. Generally, the answer is no so that is the default value.. but there are certain systems in our environment that do rely on this so I'd like to set the default value to true when it is part of a specified group.

I've thought of a few ways to accomplish the underlying goal but I'm not sure in the heart of the Ansible culture, what would be considered best practice?

Options:

A- Create and copy the entire role and only apply the copied role to the xinetd servers 
  -- Not a big fan of this as this requires maintaining multiple copies of basically the same role.

B- Modify the underlying tasks to exclude running the job when a specific group variable is defined
  -- This is a little too low-level and I'm afraid that these changes will get overlooked overtime.

C - Is perhaps the use of group variables the correct way to go? I've been doing some research into it and running some examples but I am not quite there yet... Looking for any input/recommendation on a good path forward, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern would be in your role defaults file:

```
some_feature_enabled: false
```

then, redefine the variable as a group variable, set to true. There are a couple of methods:

1) in your inventory hosts file:

```
[somegroup]
somehost

[somegroup:vars]
some_feature_enabled: true
```

2) in a dedicated group_vars file for the group. Create a directory called `group_vars` in either the directory that contains your playbook or the directory that contains the inventory file, and within that create a file named the same as your group `somegroup`. In this file:

```
some_feature_enabled: true
```

Finally add a condition to your task:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Only print this message when somefeature is enabled
  when: some_feature_enabled
```

If you have a bunch of related tasks that can be grouped together and toggled based on one value, you can wrap them in a block:

```
- block:
    - debug:
        msg: "First task"
    - debug:
        msg: "Second task"
  when: some_feature_enabled
```

If the entire role is conditional, then you can place the test at the role level:

```
roles:
  - { role: somerole, when: some_feature_enabled }
```

[This doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) gives you all the gory details around Ansible variables, crucially including information on the precedence of duplicate variables. For the Ansible teams view on best practice, [check out this doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) if you have not done already.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I went with Option 2 as that seemed to be the cleanest way to maintain/manage the differences moving forward. The key point to completing this was understanding the way Ansible prioritizes variables as described in your first link